# Rails 4: Update instance variable with AJAX

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, instance-variables

I have a search model that I use to pull `@consult_stats` from my database (following [RailsCasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/111-advanced-search-form-revised)).  Each search is a post in the Search model, and the meaningful results of a given search are found by `@search.consult_stats`

```
class Search < ActiveRecord::Base
    def consult_stats
        @consult_stats ||= find_consult_stats
    end

    private

    def find_consult_stats
        consult_stats = ConsultStat.all
        puts consult_stats.ids, 1
        consult_stats = consult_stats.joins(:weekly_report).where("weekly_reports.location_id = ?", location_id) if location_id.present?
        puts consult_stats.ids, 2
        consult_stats = consult_stats.joins(:weekly_report).where("weekly_reports.start_date >= ?", start_date) if start_date.present?
        puts consult_stats.ids, 3
        consult_stats = consult_stats.joins(:weekly_report).where("weekly_reports.start_date <= ?", end_date) if end_date.present?
        puts consult_stats.ids, 4
        consult_stats = consult_stats.where(employee_id: employee_id) if employee_id.present?

        consult_stats
    end
end
```

**Here are the controllers:**

```
class SearchesController < ApplicationController
def create
    @search = Search.new(search_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @search.save
        format.html { redirect_to @search, notice: 'Search was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @search }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @search.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
   end
end
end

def show
    respond_to do |format|
        format.json do
            @search = Search.find(params[:id])
            @consult_stats = @search.consult_stats
        end
    end
end

class LocationsController < ApplicationController
    def dashboard
        @columns = ["consults", "signed", "weeks", "extensions", "paid_in_full", "revenue", "revenue_on_account", "signed_stats"]
        @locations = Location.real
        @consult_stats = ConsultStat.all

        @revenues = []
        @employees = Employee.active.order("name ASC")
        @locations.each do |location|
            @revenues << [location.name, ConsultStat.joins(:weekly_report).where("weekly_reports.location_id = ?", location.id).sum(:revenue)]
        end
    end
end
```

This works great, but when I make my ajax request from a different controller (`LocationsController`), and try to retrieve the `@consult_stats`, the instance variable (`@consult_stats`) does not get updated.  Instead, `@consult_stats` retains its value from the `locations_contoller` (`ConsultStat.all`).

```
q = "/searches"
        $.ajax({
            url: q, 
            type: "post",
            data: {
                location_id: loc_id,
                start_date: start_date,
                end_date: end_date,
                employee_id: emp_id
            },
            success: function(data) {
                console.log("mememe", data)
                nums = []
                console.log(data) // Displays correct data!
                console.log(<%= @consult_stats %>) // Does not get updated
                $("#consult_stats").text("");

                $("#consult_stats").append("<%= escape_javascript(render 'consult_stats/consult_stat', object: @consult_stats) %>");
            },
            error: function(xhr) {
                console.log(xhr)
            },
            datatype: 'script'
        })
    })
```

**consult_stat partial**

```
<%= @consult_stats.present? ? @consult_stats.length : 0 %>
```

**Does @consult_stats not get updated because its being updated in the `search_contoller` and then reverted back in the `locations_controller`?**

Comment: Can you post the locations controller?

Comment: did that help clarify anything?